# knockout.js - updating the model after making a form element disabled/enabled

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I'm currently trying to using a Knock out View model to post to an ajax endpoint.

I'm struggling with the following scenario;

- I bind the form fields and everything is fine.
- my application has a scenario where some form fields have their `readonly` attribute set to true (using jquery  `$("#element).attr("readonly","true");`)
- After setting to read only the model gets disconnected from the control (the model item shows as null).

i've tried to enable the form elements before posting and then setting them to null after wards, but this is unsuccessful.

How to i keep the `readonly` control bound?

Comment: Some code to reproduce the problem would help. (PS. Why is jQuery setting the readonly attribute? Wouldn't it make more sense to do this with the view model ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/RJbTq/))?)

Comment: Agreed. [A basic sample](http://jsfiddle.net/58vpj/9/) seems to work OK.

Comment: jQuery is doing it because I have a combination of logic, not just MVVM. I was hoping there was an `updateBinding` or similar i could call on the field?

Comment: How does your KO model differ from that seen in my [earlier sample link](http://jsfiddle.net/58vpj/9/)? How does your jquery logic differ from that seen there also? Does changing "true" to true in your above code help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine. I was looking in the wrong place.

The problem wasn't that I Knockout wasn't updating the model. The issue was I was using jQuery to update the field alone, instead of the model.

I was doing:

```
$("#fieldName").val("new value");
$("#fieldName").attr("readonly","true");
```

This wasn't updating the Knockout model. I was using the model to submit an ajax request, so this was a problem.

by doing this instead, I have no problems:

```
viewModel.fieldName("new value);
$("#fieldName").attr("readonly","true");
```

thanks to everyone for pushing me back to using mvvm the way I should have been.